# C Programming, how to recursively get files in directories and sub directories

Tags: c, directory

So far I have this which I found here on stack overflow but this only prints out the current directory and not sub directory. Thanks in advance!

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;

if ((dir = opendir ("c:\\src\\")) != NULL) {
    /* print all the files and directories within directory */
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
        printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
    }
    closedir (dir);
} else {
    /* could not open directory */
    perror ("");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: In a simple way, put the entire code as a function (EX listDir) and inside the while readddir call listDit(ent->d_name);

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to put statements in between the if {} and else{} blocks.

Comment: could you please demonstrate for me if you dont mind? Im sort of a visual learner and im pretty new to this language.

Comment: @RichardLU I think OP wants to find all directors in the given directory, and all the directories within those directories, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your code as an example you can do:
This way it will get each directory and call the function again until it cannot find a directory.
And each call will do the same
Its just an example.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void listDir(char* path){
DIR* dir;
struct dirent *ent;
  if((dir=opendir(path)) != NULL){
    while (( ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
      if(ent->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") != 0  && strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0){
        printf("%s\n", ent->d_name);
        listDir(ent->d_name);
      }
    }
    closedir(dir);
  }
}
void main(){
  listDir(".");
}
```

Comment: hrmm this didnt seem to work. I replaced listDir("c:\\src\\") with listDir(".") cause that should start from the program's root folder right? all it did was print out a bunch of periods and then crash

Comment: `listDir(ent->d_name)` needs to do something like pseudo code `listDir(path & "/" & ent->d_name)`.  Or change working directory before call and restore afterward.

Comment: No need to use `cwd`, all you need to do is concat the found dir to the `path` you enter with and use *that* as input for the next call. But you *do* need to actively skip "." and ".." entries, lest you get an infinite loop.

Comment: Ok, now its working ok.. I check if the type is a directory and if the folder is not .. and .

Comment: You need to concat the incoming path variable with the subdirectories under it for the recursiveness to operate

Answer (score 8):

Offer the following as IMHO the accepted answer does not work.  That one only prints directories and does not recurse properly.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int listDir_helper(char* path) {
  char slash = '\\';  // or maybe slash = '/'
  DIR* dir;
  struct dirent *ent;
  char *NulPosition = &path[strlen(path)];
  if ((dir = opendir(path)) != NULL) {

    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
      printf("%s%c%s\n", path, slash, ent->d_name);
      if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR) {
        if ((strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0)) {
          sprintf(NulPosition, "%c%s", slash, ent->d_name);
          if (listDir_helper(path)) {
            closedir(dir);
            return 1;
          }
          *NulPosition = '\0';
        }
      }
    }

  }
  closedir(dir);
  return 0;
}

int listDir(const char* path){
  struct dirent *ent;
  char pathmax[MAXPATHLEN+1+sizeof(ent->d_name)+1];
  if (strlen(path) > MAXPATHLEN) {
    return 1;
  }
  strcpy(pathmax, path);
  return listDir_helper(pathmax);
}

int main() {
  listDir2("C:\\tmp");
  return 0;
}
```